# Singular or plural, subject verb agreement

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Let's suppose I am talking about people in general, but my subject of the talk is 'people', the plural noun. Now, which of the following fit best?

> 1. Their heart turns to piety.
> 2. Their hearts turn to piety.

Thing to be noted is that I am talking about all of them at a time and of course everyone has 'one' heart. So if they are 100 people, it will make a hundred hearts I am talking about.

Comment: They don't have a shared heart, as you note. Only (2) is right.

Answer (score 2):

The correct sentence is:

2. Their hearts turn to piety.

In this sentence, you have a plural subject ("hearts"). Because you are referring to more than one heart, you should use the plural ("hearts"). People is the plural form of person, so if there is more than one person's heart turning to piety, then "Their hearts turn to piety." If you were referring to one person's heart, then sentence 1 would be correct, except instead of using the plural "their," a singular noun like "one's" would be more proper, so that the sentence would read "One's heart turns to piety."